How to retrieve data for two foreign key ID and one same base table in SQL Server (with an intermediary table)?
I have a table for costing of my application which contains 2  AccountId per each row as below:
tbl_CostType:



id
DebitAccountId
CreditAccountId




1
20
22



tbl_Accounts:



id
joinAccountId




20
j1


22
j2



tbl_JoinAccounts



id
Name




j1
David


j2
Robert



How can I get the following result with a query?



debitAccountId
debitName
creditAccountId
creditName




20
David
22
Robert



SELECT 
    costType.DebitAccountId, 
    JoinAccount.Name AS debitName, 
    costype.creditAccountId, 
    JoinAccount.Name AS creditName
FROM     
    costype 
INNER JOIN  
    Account ON costype.creditAccountId = Account.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    JoinAccounts ON Accounts.JoinAccountId = JoinAccounts.Id 

But this query return a record with same value for both creditName and debitName.

I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

Join twice. Use table aliases to tell the debit rows from the credit rows:
SELECT 
  ct.debitaccountid,
  jad.name AS debitname, 
  ct.creditaccountid,
  jac.name AS creditname
FROM costype ct
JOIN account ad ON ad.id = ct.debitaccountid
JOIN jointaccounts jad ON jad.id = ad.jointaccountid
JOIN account ac ON ac.id = ct.creditaccountid
JOIN jointaccounts jac ON jac.id = ac.jointaccountid;

